# Custom buttons arangement in Android

Tags: android, button, user-interface, custom-controls

I'm trying to build an Android app where I would like to display some `Buttons` in various places, as in the **demo image** attached.
The challenge here is creating the custom buttons and arranging them.
As for the custom `Buttons`, I guess I could achieve that using `CustomViews` or a simple button with a Custom `Drawable` as Background.
Are these the right points to start, any other ideas?
On arranging them, I have no clue how to achieve that.

[image]

Comment: relative layout is best for arranging the buttions.

Comment: I've found that the best way to make custom buttons is to create your own styles and then set the appropriate style for each button. As Android_Crazy said, `RelativeLayout` is best for arranging multiple UI widgets, though it could be achieved using `AbsoluteLayout`. This layout is deprecated and use of it is discouraged, however, because it usually doesn't scale well to different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Android_Crazy and Closeratio have already said, a `RelativeLayout` is the most suitable option for custom placement of buttons in general. However, for the exact placement of buttons pictured in your example, a `LinearLayout` would work just fine.

In a `LinearLayout` you may place views under or above eachother (with `android:orientation = "vertical"`, relevant for your example) or next to each other (`android:orientation = "horizontal"`). You can also add margin to your views to alter the horizontal position (`layout_marginLeft` or `layout_marginRight`) or the vertical position (`layout_marginTop` or `layout_marginBottom`).

As for the buttons' appearance, I always use custom background drawables, usually with a custom xml to add a different drawable for when the button is being pressed or selected.